# Javascript Hide Div Reappears

Tags: javascript, html

I have set a div to hide with fading effect on document click, It hides on clicking any where but the problem is it reappears on another click and then go to hide, it should not reappear on the any another click.

I have tried like this.

Javascript Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var fired = false;
if(!fired){
document.onclick=function(){close_box_fadeOut()};
delete this.onclick;
}var fired = true;
function close_box(){
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="none";
}
function close_box_fadeOut(){
    setOpacity( 100 );
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    fadeOut();
    setTimeout(close_box, 800);
}
function setOpacity( value ) {
 document.getElementById("search-result").style.opacity = value / 10;
 document.getElementById("search-result").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
}
function fadeOut() {
 for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) 
   setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (10 - i / 10) + ')' , 8 * i );
}
</script>
enter code here
```

html Code

```
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

and Css Code

```
<style>
  #search-result{
width: 500px;
height: 25px;
background:#069;
border: 5px solid #000;
display: block;
   }
</style>
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Instant Search Codes

```
    function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
{
document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="0px";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
document.getElementById("search-result").autocomplete="off";
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
var fired  = false;
var fade = false;
document.onclick = function(){
close_box_fadeOut();
if(!fade){
document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
show_box_fadeIn()
delete this.onmouseenter;};
  };
}
document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseleave = function(){
var fade = true;
if(fade){
document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
show_box()};
 };
}
document.getElementById("search-input").onclick = function(e){
    if(!e) {
    e = window.event;
    }

    if(e.stopPropagation && e.preventDefault) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    } else {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    }show_box(); return true;
};
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","instant-search.php?keyword="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function close_box(){
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="none";
}

function close_box_fadeOut(){
if(fired ){
return;
}
fired = true;
setOpacity( 100 );
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
fadeOut();
setTimeout(close_box, 800);
}
function show_box(){
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
}
function show_box_fadeIn(){
setOpacity( 0 );
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
fadeIn()
}
function setOpacity( value ) {
document.getElementById("search-result").style.opacity = value / 10;
document.getElementById("search-result").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
}
function fadeIn() {
for( var i = 20 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )
setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (i / 5) + ')' , 5 * i );
}
function fadeOut() {
//for( var i = 20 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )
//setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (5 - i / 5) + ')' , 5 * i );
for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) 
setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (10 - i / 10) + ')' , 8 * i );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function registered with `document.onclick` is called whenever there is a click, regardless of whether or not fired is false. You need to check if fired is false inside of your `close_box_fadeOut()` function or somewhere else during that called click function.

For example:

```
function close_box_fadeOut(){
    if(fired){
        return;
    }
    setOpacity( 100 );
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    fadeOut();
    setTimeout(close_box, 800);
}
```

**Edit:** Here's how I would change all of your code to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fired = false;

document.onclick=function(){close_box_fadeOut()};

function close_box(){
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="none";
}
function close_box_fadeOut(){
    if(fired){
        return;
    }
    fired = true;
    setOpacity( 100 );
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    fadeOut();
    setTimeout(close_box, 800);
}
function setOpacity( value ) {
 document.getElementById("search-result").style.opacity = value / 10;
 document.getElementById("search-result").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
}
function fadeOut() {
 for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) 
   setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (10 - i / 10) + ')' , 8 * i );
}
</script>
```

**Edit 2:** Here's what your on click should look like.

```
document.onclick = function(){
    if(fade){
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
        show_box_fadeIn()
        delete this.onmouseenter;
    };
};
```

Comment: I tried like this using your method `    document.onclick=function(){close_box_fadeOut()};
    var fired = true;
` but now it is not hiding.

Comment: I added all of my changes to your code. I'm currently not in a place to test the code, so tell me if it still doesn't work or if you have any other questions.

Comment: Also i have set `document.getElementById("search-result").autocomplete="off";` for no browser hisory, now what is typed remains there, but i want it to disappear at page refresh, which still remains there.

Comment: Try using `document.getElementById("search-result").value = '';` at the beginning of the javascript to make its value blank. Make sure you run the javascript after the html.

Comment: Hey Jebego in i bit numb with JavaScript i am trying from 4 days with this and still not able to get it work, your method as such is working but i can not get it to work with my main codes can you have a look at my Instant Search Codes above and tell whats wrong.

Comment: I updated my post again with what your onclick function should look like. Look at the `Edit 2` section. You really don't need the `close_box_fadeOut()` function any more.

Comment: Anyways, I have to go, but I hope I was helpful!

Comment: I am stuck with my main codes still not working, Thanks Anyways i appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Your `close_box_fadeOut()` function has the line

```
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
```

This will make the element reappear before fading out again.